# Listen for network activity, and piggyback my own message when network is busy anyway

Tags: android, networking

One of the costs on a phone is that of sending messages, like for instance heartbeat messages to a service in order to be able to receive push messages.

One solution I'm trying for is to set up my timers with a time frame, for earliest heartbeat, and latest, so that when I hit the early time, I'll start listening for network traffic, and if the radio on the phone is busy anyway, I'll send my heartbeat when it is.

The idea is that I may save some power by preventing the phone from having to power up the radio just for me.

That is the theory.

But there are two problems. I'm new to Android, and I haven't been able to figure out if there is such a service I can listen to.

I'm aiming at Android 2.1 for the widest possible audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is covered in Android Training:

http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates.html

Other sections about Transferring Data Without Draining the Battery should be helpful, too.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes an answer is staring you right in the face, and you still miss it.

Comment: Just to add also, there is a free tool called ARO that will allow you to analyze the data connections and usage that may also help you. https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700312